# How do I get Bob's public key

Tags: onion-services

Hi guys I'm currently creating an Tor client in python that connects to a Hidden service

I have a question that is currently stopping me from continuing the development of this project. I am currently at the stage of sending a RELAY_COMMAND_INTRODUCE1 cell to an induction point extracted from the redv. document recieved earlier on in the steps

what i am stuck on is encrypting the data of the  RELAY_COMMAND_INTRODUCE1 cell with bob's public key

where do I find bob's public key ?

Also I notice that in the first document (encrypted) recieved from the redv. request it contains a `permanent-key` what is this,is this bob's public key

Answer (score 1):

Hidden service descriptors include the public key of the hidden service in the "permanent-key" section.